# take date from file in unix

Tags: date, unix, awk

I wanna take the date from a .txt file like this :

```
933|Mahinda|Perera|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
1129|Carmen|Lepland|female|1984-02-18|2010-02-28T04:39:58.781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer
4194|Há»“ ChÃ­|Do|male|1988-10-14|2010-03-17T22:46:17.657+0000|103.10.89.118|Internet Explorer
8333|Chen|Wang|female|1980-02-02|2010-03-15T10:21:43.365+0000|1.4.16.148|Internet Explorer
```

and compare it to a date that the user gives as input with this command :

```
./tool.sh --born-since <dateA> --born-until <dateB> -f <file>
```

and print out the lines with  the dates between those who are input..
i use this code :

```
dateA= date -d "$2" +%Y%m%d
dateB= date -d "$4" +%Y%m%d
echo $2

awk  -F'|' -v from=$2 -v to=$4 '{gsub("-","",$5);
          gsub("-","",from); gsub("-","",to)}
 from <= $5 && $5 <= to '  persons.dat.txt
```

but it just prints out :
19820529
20100101
1982-05-29

when i run 
./tool.sh --born-since 1982-05-29 --born-until 1/1/2010

Comment: What do you mean by "something is going wrong"? Tell us! How else do you expect us to help?

Comment: i edited the text, look now :D

Comment: Yes, agree with above. Show a single invocation **with argument values** and the output. If the output is not obviously wrong, please indicate the problem. Good luck.

Comment: don't bother manipulating `$2` and `$4`, For testing, just use hard coded dates in the correct format, i.e. . `-v from="20120302"` (etc) ... **AND** don't say "but it just prints out dateA, dateB , echo $2 values ..." INSTEAD copy/paste the actual output of your script. We're trying to work with the **evidence** you provide! OK!? ;-) Good luck.

Comment: it works with numbers like you told me i think :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell in my brief experiment, you don't need the `gsub` since `gawk` can compare strings by lexical order (and if your dates are `YYYY-MM-DD` and `LANG=C`, lexical and date are the same).

So I ran

```
gawk -F'|' -v from='1982-05-29' -v to='2010-01-01' '(from<=$5) && ($5<=to)' persons.dat.txt
```

and got

```
933|Mahinda|Perera|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
1129|Carmen|Lepland|female|1984-02-18|2010-02-28T04:39:58.781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer
4194|Há»“ ChÃ­|Do|male|1988-10-14|2010-03-17T22:46:17.657+0000|103.10.89.118|Internet Explorer
```

which looks like what you want to me.

The rest of your code tries to assign to `dateA` and `dateB`, but doesn't use it anywhere. Also, it looks like you're missing a `$()` there: if your intention is to put the result of your date command into `dateA`, use `dateA=$(date -d "$2" +%Y%m%d)` though given that you have YYYY-MM-DD on file, `dateA=$(date -d "$2" +%Y-%m-%d)` look slike a better plan.